# Model event is not triggered on laravel

Tags: laravel, oop

I have a class that inherits a base class and uses a trait ... I will put the code below ..

The base class is using basically to do a validation before the rescue, using for this the saving event in the boot.

The trait is to tell the class to use uuid in the id attribute .. this trait uses the creating event of the boot.

In the class itself, the boot saving event is used to check if an active record exists.

In this code the trait creating event is not being triggered ... I can not do a save because uuid is not generated ... if I take the boot method in the final class the creating event is executed ...

something I'm not seeing ... does anybody have any idea what may be happening?

MAIN CLASS

```
class AcademicYear extends BaseModel
{
    use UseUuid;

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            if($model->attributes['disable'] == false){
                $model->searchActiveRecord();
            }
        });
    }

    public function searchActiveRecord(){
        if ($this::where('disable', false)->count() >= 1){
            throw new \App\Exceptions\OperationNotAllowed('operation not allowed', 'there is an active record', '422');
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

BASE MODEL

```
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * If the model will be validated in saving
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected static $validate = true;

    /**
     * Rules that will be used to validate the model
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $validationRules = [];

    /**
     * Create a new base model instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function($model)
        {
            if ($model::$validate) {
                $model->validate();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Execute validation of model attributes.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($this->attributesToArray(), $this->validationRules);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            throw new \App\Exceptions\OperationNotAllowed('validation failed', $validator->messages(), '422');
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

TRAIT

```
trait UseUuid
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model)
        {
            $model->incrementing = false;
            $model->keyType = 'string';

            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Str::uuid()->toString();

        });

        static::retrieved(function ($model)
        {
            $model->incrementing = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model's `boot` method is conflicting with the trait's `boot` method, because they have the same name.

From [the PHP.net manual on Traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.precedence):

> An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member inserted by a Trait. The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.

Current class: `AcademicYear`
Trait: `UseUuid`
Inherited class: `BaseModel`

If you want to use a `boot` method on an individual model, you'll have to alias the trait's method to something different:

```php
class AcademicYear extends BaseModel
{
    use UseUuid {
        boot as uuidBoot;
    }

    // ...

    protected static function boot()
    {
        static::uuidBoot();

        // Your model-specific boot code here.
    }
}
```

**Be careful with where you place `parent::boot()`.** If you call `parent::boot()` in both your trait *and* your model, `BaseModel::boot()` will be called more than once.

Comment: it worked here .. I had understood the concept .. but the use I did not know .. ok .. this way I did it is not elegant ... any suggestions on how to do this in a smarter way ??